# Split Traffic in REST API for A/B Testing

Tags: python, algorithm, random

I have an rest API written in Django Python Framework , I want to split the traffic which is coming to API in the fixed ratio (For ex. 30% for Flow A and 70% for Flow B).What is the best way to achieve the above without using the database.

Comment: Can't you just do it randomly?

Answer (score 1):

As ToTheMax mentioned, roll a biased dice of probability 0.3 for each incoming data point.

```
from scipy.stats import bernoulli
isFlowA = bernoulli.rvs(0.3)
```

`isFlowA` will be `1` with probability `0.3`.